# Buoyancy / Drag Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, terminology, drag, buoyancy

Buoyancy / Drag Problem

Just a little bit of help would be nice.

I have a spherical particle of radius $R$ and density $\rho$, surrounded in a fluid of density $\phi$ and viscosity $\eta$. I'm suppose to consider the forces of gravity, buoyancy, and drag.

I'm them told to consider the net force on the particle at steady state and then to find the sedimentation velocity of of the particle in terms of the problem's parameters.

So, here are my questions

1) What is the sedimentation velocity? My notes and book have no record of this term, at the wikipedia article on sedimentation coefficient just list it as terminal velocity, so I assume that's what is meant, but I'm just checking.

2) Isn't the net force just the drag since buoyancy and gravity would cancel each other out - or do I misunderstand this concept?

Comment: Sedimentation velocity is terminal velocity. Gravity and the buoyancy force would only equal if the density of the particle were equal to the density of the surrounding medium. Assuming the particle is falling down, the gravitational force will be balanced by *the sum* of the drag and buoyancy forces.

Comment: @BrysonS. that should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Yes sedimentation velocity is terminal velocity.

2)No, Not necessarily. Buoyancy Depends on the *Volume* of water displace by the object where as gravitational force is weight of object. 
Let us look at 2 cases here:

Constant values:

g, Gravitational acceleration = 10 m/s<sup>2</sup>

d, Density of water = 10<sup>3</sup> Kg m<sup>3</sup>


CASE I: 
V, Volume=10<sup>3</sup> m<sup>3</sup>
 
 D, Density object= 10<sup>3</sup> Kg/m<sup>3</sup>
  
 B, Bouyancy= vdg = 1000 * 1000 * 10 = 10<sup>7</sup> N

 W, Weight of Body = VDg = 10<sup>3</sup> * 10<sup>3</sup> * 10 = 10<sup>7</sup>N

Here, W = B and they cancel each other out.

CASE II:
V, Volume=10<sup>3</sup> m<sup>3</sup>
 
 D, Density object= 10<sup>2</sup> Kg/m<sup>3</sup>
  
 B, Bouyancy= vdg = 1000 * 1000 * 10 = 10<sup>7</sup> N

 W, Weight of Body = VDg = 10<sup>3</sup> * 10<sup>2</sup> * 10 = 10<sup>6</sup>N

Here you can see that W is not= B and they don't cancel each other.

Thus we can conclude that for weight and buoyancy to cancel each other, Density of liquid should be equal to density of object.